# Reaction on a reaction on a reaction

Tags: html, css, width, margin, center

The problem is that when users respond on each others posts i have to do like:

```
margin-left:40px;
```

For 1 level deep reaction

```
margin-left:80px;
```

For 2 levels deep etc.

However i want to make the reactions div the center of the page:

```
.reactions {margin: 50px auto 0 auto; width: 1100px;}
```

But i don't want to limet the "levels of reactions" be limited by the width of the page.
There should just be some horizontal scrollbar.

Im searching for a working version of:

```
.reactions {margin: 50px auto 0 auto; width:100%;}
```

Anybody ideas/comments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how your HTML is set up, but if you append the reply post inside the container of the original post, you can just use `position: relative` and keep `margin-left: 40px`

Comment: Nah. Fixed it using this:http://www.cssplay.co.uk/menus/centered.html
Thanks for trying tough :)